# Manage htaccess via custom CMS?

Tags: php, .htaccess

my client uses 301 redirects in htaccess to redirect random "URLs" they publish in ads etc to actual site pages which have /one-word addresses.

Is it possible on Apache/PHP to somehow remotely manage these 301 redirects IN the htaccess file? I know I can modify headers per page which yes, would be a solution. But this client won't always have an actual page to redirect from...they just pull stuff outa the air and want to redirect.

Possible? Thanks.

Comment: You mean manage as in edit the .htaccess file programmatically? Sure, that's possible. Your script would have to parse the .htaccess file, and put it together again.

Comment: It might be easier using a RewriteMap. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html

Comment: thanks for the tips, I'll look into these. seems as though 'yes' it is possible.